# Referenciando Variáveis Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, escopo-de-variáveis, referência

Estou aprendendo programação por conta própria e por mais que procure online, não consigo entender exatamente porque a referência a seguir não funciona como imagino que funcionaria.

Digamos que eu tenha criado uma função para fazer uma pergunta:

```
def Pergunta(X, Y):  
    X = input(Y)
```

Em seguida, eu chamo o método e adiciono uma saudação:

```
Pergunta(Resposta, 'Qual o seu nome?')
print('Sejam bem-vindos, {}'.format(Resposta))
```

O Python então reclama que a variável `Resposta` não está definido, logo, imagino que preciso referenciar a variável antes e esta foi minha solução:

```
def Pergunta(X, Y):  
    X = input(Y)

Resposta = ''
Pergunta(Resposta, 'Qual o seu nome?')
print('Sejam bem-vindos, {}!'.format(Resposta))
```

Aparentemente isso resolve o problema, mas quando testo o programa, a referência em que `Resposta = ''` não é sobreposta pela função que deveria transforma-la em `"Leandro"`, por exemplo. Ao invés disso, o programa apenas imprime:

```
Sejam bem-vindos, !
```

Alguém sabe me explicar o que estou fazendo de errado ou porque a função não reescreve a referência ou o que eu devo fazer para que ele funcione dessa maneira ?

Uma coisa que me confunde: quando eu escrevo esse comando dentro do método `format`, por algum motivo a referência funciona, mas eu queria que essa saudação fosse independente do método.

Agradeço a atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro de tudo, você deve saber que a variável `Resposta` e a variável `X` na sua função são diferentes. Primeiro porque a nomenclatura é diferente, então se você quiser alterar a variável `Resposta`, você deveria ter dentro da sua função uma variável com o mesmo nome. Exemplo:

```
def Pergunta(Y):  
    Resposta = input(Y)
```

Note duas coisas nesse exemplo acima. A primeiro coisa é que eu retirei o parâmetro `X` da assinatura do método. Talvez você pense que ao passar `Resposta` para `X` você passa a referência, mas isso não funciona com **tipos primitivos** em Python, na verdade, o que você faz é passar somente o valor da variável.

Passar a referência como argumento para uma função só funciona em **objetos** como listas, tuplas, e outros. Exemplo:

```
# O que é passado para o parâmetro não é um valor e sim um endereço de memória, 
# já que se é passado uma lista e não um tipo primitivo.

def limpa(lista):  
    lista.clear()

minhaLista = [1,2,3]
limpa(minhaLista)
```

A segunda coisa que podemos notar ao executar essa função é que mesmo corrigindo o problema de nome de variável, o resultado ainda não será o que desejamos ou até mesmo será gerado um erro, como o que acontecia com você antes.

```
def Pergunta(Y):  
    Resposta = input(Y)

Pergunta('Qual o seu nome?')
print('Sejam bem-vindos, {}!'.format(Resposta))
```

> NameError: name 'Resposta' is not defined

Isso ocorre porque a variável `Resposta` dentro da função está em um escopo totalmente diferente da variável `Resposta` fora da função. Logo o erro no exemplo acima é gerado pois a variável `Resposta` só existe dentro da função.

Para entender melhor sobre o assunto de escopo eu recomendo que você leia o artigo [neste](http://www.bosontreinamentos.com.br/programacao-em-python/funcoes-em-python-escopos-de-variaveis/) site. Mas simplificando tudo, o escopo da variável dentro da sua função é o escopo **local** e fora da função, a sua variável está no escopo **global**.

```
Resposta = ""  # Escopo global

def Pergunta(Y):  
    Resposta = input(Y)  # Escopo local
```

A variável do escopo *global* não será alterada pois o escopo *local* não tem ligação com ela. Mas nós podemos alterar a variável do escopo *global* dentro da função utilizando a declaração `global`. Veja abaixo:

```
def Pergunta(Y): 

    # Declara que a variável não pertence 
    # ao escopo local, e sim ao escopo global. 
    global Resposta

    Resposta = input(Y)
```

Há também uma outra declaração chamada `nonlocal` que tem o mesmo objetivo da declaração `global`, porém ele vai obter a variável do escopo da função mais externa. Exemplo:

```
# Escopo global (fora de funções, classes, métodos e outros)

def obterIdade(): # Escopo da função 1 (dentro da função obterIdade)

    idade = 15

    def acrescentaIdade(): # Escopo da função 2 (dentro da função acrescentaIdade)

        # Utilizar a declaração global não funcionaria pois a variável
        # não está no escopo global, e sim no escopo local da função 1.
        nonlocal idade
        idade += 1
```

Fora isso, você também deve saber sobre o `return`. Essa declaração serve para retornar um ou mais valores de uma função. Dessa forma não é necessário alterarmos diretamente na função a variável *global*. Exemplo:

```
def Pergunta(Y):  
    nome = input(Y)
    return nome

resposta = Pergunta('Qual o seu nome?') # Obtém o valor retornado da função
print('Sejam bem-vindos, {}!'.format(resposta))
```

Agora que você aprendeu tudo sobre escopos, declaração `global` e `nonlocal`, você pode corrigir e melhorar seu código, dessa forma:

```
# Dica: Tenha sempre a atenção de criar nomes 
# bem definidos para suas variáveis e funções ;)

def perguntar(texto):
    global resposta
    resposta = input(texto)

perguntar('Qual o seu nome?')
print('Sejam bem-vindos, {}!'.format(resposta))
```

Comment: JeanExtreme002, gratíssimo: era exatamente isso que eu precisava entender! Práticamente uma aula!

Comment: Desculpe abusar da boa vontade. Consegui fazer funcionar, mas quando fui importar essa função para outro documento percebi que a situação se repete com a referência, mesmo atribuindo "Global" à variável. 

Li a matéria que você me referenciou, mas não encontrei menção a uma escala fora ou acima do global para fazer elas conversarem e Return também não fez a ponte entre os escopos. Nesse caso a referência só funciona se a função estiver dentro do próprio arquivo, então?

Comment: Em relação a essa sua primeira duvida, eu recomendo que você faça uma outra pergunta no site para que eu ou outros possam te responder, e como você disse, o `return` não faz ponte entre escopos realmente. O que o comando `return` faz é simplesmente retornar um valor, mas a variável usada dentro da função **morre** ao final da execução da função. Logo você não pode reutilizar a variável criada dentro da função, mas pode obter o valor retornado pela função com o sinal de atribuição assim como demonstrei no meu exemplo.

Comment: Entendi. Criei então outra dúvida, já que o assunto parece ser outro. Grato!

Answer (score 0):

Importante lembrar que em python as `string` são imutáveis com isso se passar um tipo imutável em um método não será passado sua referencia, consequentemente não será possível alterar.

Porém se fizer isso com um objeto mutável, como uma lista, por exemplo. Será feita a passagem de referencia através do método e sendo assim será possível alterar o objeto. Utilizando o seu exemplo só mudando o tipo da variável de `string` para `list`

```
Resposta = list()

def Pergunta(X, Y):
    X.append(input(Y))

Pergunta(Resposta, 'Qual o seu nome?')
print('Sejam bem-vindos, {}!'.format(Resposta[0]))
```

Temos o seguinte output:

```
Qual o seu nome? Thiago
Sejam bem-vindos, Thiago!
```